# Oracle Update statement

Tags: oracle11g

Am trying to update a table which is little tricky. Let me try to explain..
E.g here is the table data

[image]

here is how i want to update col5.
For each record, check if col3 has a value, if yes check that value is in col2. if both conditions satisfied, get max of col1 since col2 will have duplicates.
If col3 does not have a value we need to check col4 and compare to col2 and get col1.

Eg: for row 5, i will check col3 first, it has a value of 'b', i will check col2 for value 'b', i have 3 matching's (col1 - id 2,7,9) will need to take 9  from col1 and update col5 at row 5.

Please suggest your valuable thought's/ideas..

Answer (score 0):

I have coded for your first condition, where you match col3 (for both existing and not existing condition), you can similary write the code inside the procedure to match col4.

```
create or replace procedure proc_cal is
  d_col1 varchar2(3);
  d_col2 varchar2(3);
  maxcol varchar2(3):= '0';
begin
  for i in (select * from coldata) loop
  dbms_output.put_line('in here '|| i.col3);
    if (i.col3 is not null) then
      dbms_output.put_line('value exists for col3 and is ' || i.col3);
      for j in (select * from coldata) loop

        if (j.col2 = i.col3) then
          dbms_output.put_line('value exists for col2 and col1 value is ' ||
                               j.col1);
         dbms_output.put_line('the prev maxcol is '|| maxcol);
          if (maxcol < j.col1) then
          dbms_output.put_line('checking'); 
           maxcol := j.col1;

            dbms_output.put_line('current maxcol is  ' || maxcol);

          end if;
        end if;

      end loop;
      update coldata set col5 = maxcol where col3=i.col3;
        dbms_output.put_line('max value update and is ' || maxcol);
        maxcol:=0;

    else
      update coldata set col5 = null where col3=i.col3;
      end if;
  end loop;
end;



SCOTT@research 13-APR-15> select * from coldata;

COL COL COL COL COL
--- --- --- --- ---
1   a       a
2   b       c
3   a   a       8
4   c       c
5   a   b       9
6   c       b
7   b   c   e   10
8   a       a
9   b       b
10  c       c
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future it would awesome if you could provide a CREATE DDL and some INSERT statements for your example, but here is a non-procedural solution.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
       col1 NUMBER,
       col2 VARCHAR2(1),
       col3 VARCHAR2(1),
       col4 VARCHAR2(1),
       col5 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'a', NULL, 'a', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'b', NULL, 'c', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'a', 'a', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'c', NULL, 'c', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'a', 'b', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, 'c', NULL, 'b', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7, 'b', 'c', 'e', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (8, 'a', NULL, 'a', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (9, 'b', NULL, 'b', NULL);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (10, 'c', NULL, 'c', NULL);

UPDATE t t1
   SET t1.col5 =
       (SELECT MAX(t2.col1)
          FROM t t2
         WHERE t2.col2 = t1.col3)
 WHERE t1.col3 IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
  FROM t;
/*
col col col col col
1   a       a 
2   b       c 
3   a   a       8
4   c       c 
5   a   b       9
6   c       b 
7   b   c   e   10
8   a       a 
9   b       b 
10  c       c 
*/
```